# Open problems in compressed sensing

Tags: co.combinatorics, linear-algebra, open-problems, compressed-sensing

What are the main open problems in compressed sensing?

I am interested in theoretical as well as in numerical point of view.

Comment: This is not a sure finalist for the best question ever competition, of course, but why to downvote (especially without any explanation of what exactly you dislike)????

Comment: There used to be a maxim on MO of the form "MathOverflow is not for people to request other people to write encyclopaedia entries for them". I therefore suggest that Felix should try to narrow his question down first, after looking online at research and survey articles in compressed sensing

Comment: @YemonChoi Well, I have an idea of what compressed sensing is - having read some articles and knowing a thing or two about linear algebra and signal processing, as background. But I cannot really tell which are the more fundamental problems, as opposed to sheer technicalities. That's why I asked for knowledgeable people, to give their estimate of what the main problems are - a bit like my old question http://mathoverflow.net/questions/118545/what-are-the-major-open-problems-in-design-theory-nowaday which I think worked rather well. I did *not* ask anyone to write an encyclopaedia entry for me.

Comment: One thing is that it makes a huge difference if one answers this question as a mathematician or as an engineer. Well, of course this is site for mathematics but the idea of compressed sensing is really a practical one: get information about a high dimensional object that lives in lower dimensional but nonlinear subspace from few measurements. The meaning of all ingredients is debatable here and varies a lot from problem to problem.  Hence one open problem is to find the right mathematical formulation of the problem...

Answer (score 5):

A relatively recent (2012) overview of open problems and challenges in compressive sensing has been written by [Thomas Strohmer.](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=6338308) A somewhat older (2007) listing by [Terence Tao](http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2007/04/15/ostrowski-lecture-the-uniform-uncertainty-principle-and-compressed-sensing/) is still timely:

> - A first question is derandomisation; all of the measurement ensembles for which the really strong compressed sensing results are known have to be generated by a random process; no deterministic compressed sensing method which is rigorously backed by theory is known.
> - Another question is to see whether one can improve the two basic algorithms of basis pursuit and matching pursuit and obtain better results (in either accuracy, speed, or robustness); given the lack of lower bounds in this subject it is difficult to tell how close the current algorithms are to being optimal.
> - A third is to relax the hypotheses on the measurement ensemble, in particular to allow for some limited amount of linear dependence (or near-dependence) between columns of the measuremement matrix.